# Javascript in <head> of html file not working

Tags: javascript, html, maven, tomcat

So i have this code, with should connect to google api and get some info of the user. The problem however is that the link which starts the login function doesn't work.

This is a java RESTful project so its built via maven and deployed on a tomcat server if that helps.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascipt'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var OAUTHURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
  var VALIDURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=';
  var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
  var CLIENTID = 'sercret';
  var REDIRECT = 'myredirect';
  var LOGOUT = 'http://accounts.google.com/Logout';
  var TYPE = 'token';
  var url1 = OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;
  var acToken;
  var tokenType;
  var expiresIn;
  var user;
  var loggedIn = false;
  function login(){
      var win = window.open(url1, 'windowname1', 'width=800, height=600'); 
      var pollTimer = window.setInterval(function() {
          try {
              console.log(win.document.URL);
              if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                  window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                  var url =   win.document.URL;
                  acToken =   gup(url, 'access_token');
                  tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                  expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                  win.close(); 
                  validateToken(acToken);
              }
          } catch(e) {
          }
      }, 500);
  });
  function validateToken(token) {
      $.ajax({
          url: VALIDURL + token,
          data: null,
          success: function(responseText){
              getUserInfo();
              loggedIn = true;
              $('#loginText').hide();
              $('#logoutText').show();
          }, 
          dataType: 'jsonp'
      });
  }
  function getUserInfo() {
      $.ajax({
          url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken,
          data: null,
          success: function(resp) {
              user    =   resp;
              console.log(user);
              $('#uName').text('Welcome ' + user.name);
              $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
          },
          dataType: 'jsonp'
      });
  }
  /*credits: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html*/
  function gup(url, name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\\\\[]/,'\\\[').replace(/[\]]/,'\\\]');
      var regexS = '[\\#&]'+name+'=([^&#]*)';
      var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
      var results = regex.exec( url );
      if( results === null )
          return ;
      else
          return results[1];
  }
  function startLogoutPolling() {
      $('#loginText').show();
      $('#logoutText').hide();
      loggedIn = false;
      $('#uName').text('Welcome ');
      $('#imgHolder').attr('src', 'none.jpg');
  }
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick='login()' id='loginText'> Click here to login </a>
    <a href="#" style='display:none' id='logoutText' target='myIFrame' onclick="myIFrame.location='https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout'; startLogoutPolling();return false;"> Click here to logout </a>
    <iframe name='myIFrame' id='myIFrame' style='display:none'></iframe>
    <div id='uName'></div>
    <img src='' id='imgHolder'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Small Error, big waste of time :)

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
```

You have missed the 'r' in javascipt

Comment: and you've put it in the wrong place. Plz change it to `javascript`

Answer (score 0):

This is looking for a function called `login`:

```
onclick='login()'
```

However, no such function exists in the current scope.  It was defined only within the scope of the `document.ready` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function login() {
        //...
    }
});
```

So it's not visible outside of the handler.  In order to make it visible, define it outside:

```
function login() {
    //...
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //...
});
```

You generally don't need to define your functions in `document.ready`, it's mainly for waiting until the DOM is loaded before evaluating selectors.  You *can* define functions within it, if those functions don't need to exist outside its scope.

Another alternative would be to bind it within the scope that it's defined, rather than in-line in the markup.  Something like this:

```
$(document.ready(function () {
    function login() {
        //...
    }

    $('#loginText').click(login);
});
```